# How to access HDD folder when booting from USB? (permission denied)

Tags: permissions

so, as described in a different question, my regular ubuntu installation is broken at the moment, and I'm booting from a USB. naturally I'd like to make sure everything is backed up, but for some reason I can not access one of the folders on the HDD. I can open most, but this one in particular says:

```
The Folder contents could not be displayed
You do not have the permissions necessary to to view contents of "LIFnetworks".
```

what now? is there a way to "root" my way around this?, or does this mean that my computer is more broken than I thought? I don't have any good reason why that folder should have different permissions than the others. it's really the only important one, so it's quite a problem.

I hope the question makes sense :)

EDIT:
Going with Achu's suggestion, I get the following:

```
sudo nautilus
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.


(nautilus:5836): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: Missing callback called fullpath = /root/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

On screen, I got a dialog saying that it couldn't create a file (sorry, I didn't copy the text). When I redo the command, I don't get the dialog, but the nautilus-window which opens doesn't see the devices, which includes the file system of the broken ubuntu installation. Opening nautilus from the sidebar, the devices are still there.

Comment: You can be a root by typing sudo -i on terminal and access the folder from there.I think it work for you.

Comment: beeju's version worked :) I'm afraid I don't have enough rep to plus-one a comment, but if you make it an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open terminal and type

> sudo nautilus

A new Windows will pop up with root privilege.

- Now, you have access privilege :)